# What is the difference between an API and an Integration (Marketo)

Tags: rest, email, marketo

My company wants our IT department to review and approve every tool we connect to Marketo. This is a lengthy and costly approach which I do not seem to fully understand, why. For example, I would like to use the Marketo integration with LinkedIn, Contact Forms 7 (WordPress plugin), or Zoom. There are already existing integrations with Marketo which can easily set up via the API Code provided by Marketo. However, my company wants to review all these as all API integrations have to be reviewed by IT. Does this make sense from a security or functionality perspective? Are the existing Linkedin, Zoom, WordPress integrations proper API connections? What is the difference between an API and integration in Marketo?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think with the API integration, that would use your own daily API limit whereas the native (existing) connection in Marketo where you can connect to Linkedin or Zoom integration is via Marketo background API which does not count towards your limit. In terms of security review, you might want to discuss to get the details off your Account Manager perhaps.